# Trying to retrieve the Dynamics 365 Form Order with the REST API

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

We are pulling systemForm data from Dynamics with the REST API:

```
https://jj-----jj.crm6.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/systemforms?$filter=objecttypecode eq 'lead' and type eq 2 and componentstate eq 0 and formactivationstate eq 1
```

This works well except we need to determine which is the default systemForm.

The way I understand it this can only be determined by returning the Form Order.

[image]

I can't see a REST API that returns this information. Does anybody know if this is possible via REST API? If not how do we determine the default Form to work with?

Comment: Hey, what are you trying to achieve here? Maybe we can get your end result another way.

Comment: in your condition I would add also type eq 2 (or any other valid value) to return just the form type you need (2 is "Main"). I checked but I can't find an API (also inside the EntityDefinitions endpoint) to retrieve the form order (and the property isdefault from systemform doesn't hold the setting you are looking for)

Comment: Hi @GuidoPreite yes - we are looking for the main form that renders for the user by default. We have an external client that uses REST API to to render a version of this default Form.  I pretty much came to the same conclusion as you - I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @MoneyMurch - we are looking to replicate the user experience of rendering the default main form (in our client) for the user using only API calls.  We know nothing of the users environment and can only use API calls.  We need to know which form to render.